# why $S(F,U)$ is a sub-basis for $C([0,1];X)$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space. Let $Z = C([0,1];X)$ be the set of all continuous maps from $[0,1]$ to $X$. For each closed subset $F\subset [0,1]$ and open subset $U\subset X$, define a set $S(F,U) := \{\alpha \in Z| \alpha(F) \subset U\}$.

I want to show $b$ which is the collection of $S(F,U)$ for all closed sets in $[0,1]$ and $U$ open in $X$ be a subbasis for $Z$ and shape of topology on $Z$.

---

After searching on the internet, I realized this is similar to compact-open topology and in Wikipedia, it just states the collection of all such as a subbase for the compact-open topology but does not state why.

First of all, I am not familiar with compact-open topology.

Comment: What topology on $C([0,1],X)$ are you using? And what's the *definition* of that topology???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich is it necessary to know the topology of $C([0,1];X)$? It seems he wants to induce a topology on the set $Z$ (i.e. he is regarding $Z$ topologyless a priori).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first observe that for each set $M$ and each collection $\mathscr S$ of subsets of $M$ there exists a *coarsest topology* $\mathscr T[\mathscr S]$ on $M$ such that $\mathscr S \subset \mathscr T[\mathscr S]$.

In fact, let $\mathfrak T[\mathscr S]$ denote the set of all topologies on $M$ which contain $\mathscr S$ as a subset. Clearly $\mathfrak T[\mathscr S] \ne \emptyset$ because the discrete topology on $M$ is an element of $\mathfrak T[\mathscr S]$. Now we can define
$$\mathscr T[\mathscr S] = \bigcap_{\mathscr T \in \mathfrak T[\mathscr S]} \mathscr T .$$
Any intersection of topologies is again a topology, thus by definition $\mathscr T[\mathscr S]$ has the desired property. Clearly it is uniquely determined by $\mathscr S$. We can say that $\mathscr T[\mathscr S]$ is the topology *generated by the given $\mathscr S$*. It is a nice exercise to verify that $\mathscr S$ is a *subbasis* for the topology $\mathscr T[\mathscr S]$. Therefore we can alternatively say that $\mathscr T[\mathscr S]$ is *the topology with subbase $\mathscr S$*.

This is a general method for topologizing a set $M$: Define a collection $\mathscr S$ of subsets of $M$ and give $M$ the topology  $\mathscr T[\mathscr S]$ with subbase  $\mathscr S$.

A standard approach to topologize the set $C(Y,Z)$ of all continuous functions $f :  Y \to X$ is to give it the *compact-open topology*. Define $$\mathscr S = \{ S(F,U) \mid F \subset Y \text{ compact}, U \subset X \text{ open}\}.$$
Then the compact-open topology is defined as the unique topology having $\mathscr S$ as a subbase.

In your example $Z = C([0,1],X)$ the compact subsets of $[0,1]$ are precisley the closed subsets.